# Date from yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss to yyyy-MM-dd format in JSP

Tags: jsp, datetime

I had a a problem with jsp date format and I want in the checkbox to be like `dd/mm/yyyy` and not `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss`, any solution?
This is my code:

```
String sql1= "SELECT * from ajout_train";
          PreparedStatement st1 = cnx.prepareStatement(sql1);
```

```
       <tbody style="width: 105px">

       <tr>
          <td><label for="datedept">Départ le:</label></td>
            <td> <select name="datedept" id="datedept"><%
             if (st1.execute()) {
               ResultSet rs1 = st1.getResultSet();
               ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs1.getMetaData();

          while(rs1.next()) {

           if (rs1.getObject(4) != null){

           out.println("<option>"+rs1.getObject(4).toString()+"</option>");
           }
           }
           }
           %></select><%

         %></td>
       </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is inbuild class in java to format date 
Use this snippet. you can Refer this link [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details

```
if (rs1.getObject(4) != null){


    SimpleDateFormat inputdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat outputdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        try {

            String result = outputdate.format(inputdate.parse(rs1.getObject(4).toString()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }
               out.println("<option>"+result+"</option>");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but it doesn't work because jsp didn't know the type SimpleDateFormat i put an import but same thing.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved with substring

`enter code here`
           
              Départ le:
                 <%
                 if (st1.execute()) 
                 {
                   ResultSet rs1 = st1.getResultSet();
                   ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs1.getMetaData();

```
                while(rs1.next()) 
                { 
                    if (rs1.getObject(4) != null){ 
                        String result=(String)(rs1.getObject(4).toString());
                        result=result.substring(0,10);
                        out.println("<option>"+result+"</option>");
                        }
                }
             }
             %></select><%
         %></td>
       </tr>
```